# Alternative to path() in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my URLs.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
path('moraimono/', include('moraimono.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

however I found that path() is only included in Django 2.0 and I am using Django 1.11b1.

How can I modify this code to make it work in Django 1.11b1

Comment: `url(r'^moraimono/', include('moraimono.urls')))`

Comment: Friendly reminder: Django `1.11b1` has a number of known bugs and security issues. If you can't update to Django `2.0.x`, you should update to the latest point-release of Django `1.11.x` (which is `1.11.9` at the time of writing).

Answer (score 2):

Just use `url()` instead of `path()`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^moraimono/', include('moraimono.urls')),
]
```

Find more details in `url` documentation's [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#url)

Answer (score 2):

`urlpatterns` should be a list of `url()` instances. :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', index_view, name='main-view'),
    url(r'^moraimono/', include('moraimono.urls')),
    ...
]
```

`url()` is defined internally as:

```
def url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None):
    if isinstance(view, (list, tuple)):
        # For include(...) processing.
        urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view
        return RegexURLResolver(regex, urlconf_module, kwargs, app_name=app_name, namespace=namespace)
    elif callable(view):
        return RegexURLPattern(regex, view, kwargs, name)
    else:
        raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
```

Answer (score 0):

use `url`, you already have it imported and in django 2.0 it's synonymous with `re_path`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^'moraimono/$', include('moraimono.urls')),
    url(r'^'admin/$', admin.site.urls),
]
```